# How to capture 2 different patterns one from the beginnig and other from the end of the string using Regular Expression?

Tags: regex, python-3.7, regex-group

I need to capture two different patterns one from the beginning of the string and the other from the end.

I am using Python3.

Example 1:

```
string: 'TRADE ACCOUNT BALANCE FROM 2 TRADE LINES CALL. .... $ 23,700'
expected_output: TRADE ACCOUNT BALANCE 23,700
my_regex_pattern: r'(TRADE ACCOUNT BALANCE).+([\d,]+)'
output(group 0): TRADE ACCOUNT BALANCE
output(group 1): 0
```

Example 2:

```
string: 'AVERAGE BALANCE IN THE PAST 5 QUARTERS ......... $ 26,460'
output: AVERAGE BALANCE 26,460
my_regex_pattern: r'(AVERAGE BALANCE).+([\d,]+)'
output(group 0): AVERAGE BALANCE
output(group 1): 0
```

**The substring, in the end, will always be a number. The substring, in the beginning, will always be a word**
I do not understand why it is capturing just the last character from the end.

Comment: Because `.+` is capturing as much as possible. Try `(TRADE ACCOUNT BALANCE).*\s(\S+)` or `(TRADE ACCOUNT BALANCE).*\s([\d,]+)` - many variations exist, just find a stopper for `.+` or use two regex patterns: `^TRADE ACCOUNT BALANCE|[\d,]+$`

Comment: A possible solution is to require a whitespace before the number: `(TRADE ACCOUNT BALANCE).*\s(\d[\d,]*)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/PatmeP/1). Another "anchor" is the `$` char: `(TRADE ACCOUNT BALANCE).*\$\s*([\d,]+)`, see [another regex](https://regex101.com/r/lVPsGB/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew both of your solution works. I understand what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.+` in your pattern matches the whole string to the end, and then backtracks to find the first occurrence that matches `[\d,]+` pattern. Since the last `0` meets this criterion, that match succeeds with just `0` in the second group.

What you need to do in this situation is to find where to "anchor" the second group start.

In the strings you provided, there is a dollar symbol before the number. So, you may use

```
(TRADE ACCOUNT BALANCE).*\$\s*(\d[\d,]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/18hDPS/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(TRADE%20ACCOUNT%20BALANCE).*%5C%24%5Cs*(%5Cd%5B%5Cd%2C%5D*)):

[image]

**Details**

- `(TRADE ACCOUNT BALANCE)` - Group 1: a literal substring
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\$` - a `$` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d[\d,]*)` - Group 2: a digit, and then 0+ digits or commas.